# React Native-How do I start a TextInput with a value read from AsyncStorage when loading/rendering the screen first time in functional component?

Tags: reactjs, native, textinput, asyncstorage

I've tried several ways without success with the useEffect hook.
And I haven't found the solution anywhere.
The purpose is to read the email saved in AsyncStorage and automatically populate the TextInput when loading the login screen (like as defaultvalue).
Could anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post some of your tries and the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used this way:
my handling:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState();
const demo = async () => {
try {
  const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('_token');
  setValue(data);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
};
useEffect(() => {
  demo();
}, []);
```

display part:

```
<TextInput
    style={{width: 100, height: 50, marginTop: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
    value={value}
    onChangeText={setValue}
  />
```